# Does die() do an ob_end_flush()?

Tags: php, output-buffering, die

I can't seem to find a good answer on this anywhere. If I am running output buffering, and a `die()` is fired, does that kick off an `ob_end_flush()` as well?

Comment: I do see pending buffers when the script ends (die or not die, CLI or HTTP). I don't know if it's documented and/or configurable; I agree it'd be interesting to find an explicit reference to it in the manual.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it does.  Any time the script ends gracefully, the buffers will be emptied.  The only non-graceful endings are if it segmentation faults or if it's killed (signal 9 SIG_KILL).  The only place that `die()` does a hard-kill of the process is if you call it inside of a `register_shutdown_function` (But the buffers are flushed before the shutdown function is called, so there's no issue there).  See [Connection Handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php) for some more information...

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

However, you can make the output empty if you have

```
register_shutdown_function('ob_clean');
```

earlier in the code.

In some cases we did not want to output the ob on a die().
I write this here in case it could help anyone who wants to do the same.